# How to make the child of a view fill the space (match_parent) but keep growing if necessary?

Tags: android, view

I have a TextView inside a LinearLayout and I want the background of my TextView to always display blue, filling the space horizontally, esto es lo que necesito:

[image]
[image]

But I don't know how to get it, the contained text can change, if I set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` it won't show all the text when there are long texts. And if I use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` it will look like this:

[image]

This is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout...>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/week"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView...>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how large can your text can get? As you know, in portrait mode the screen space is very limited. You may have to trade-off of showing the whole text in portrait mode and use ellipsize or make the textview multiline.

Comment: @Kozmotronik The text cannot be that long, it could show the texts: Day X, Week X, Fortnight X, Month X. Where X can be a 1 or 3 digit number. The problem is that you cannot know the probable largest text size because those words are written differently in the different languages that the application will be in.

Comment: I see, first of all you must set the width to `match_parent`. After doing this you have several options each of which comes with a trade-off unfortunately. Ellipsize from middle or end. If it is important to display all characters then you can try to use the marquee property. Another option would be to use multiline when needed. Resizing the text according to the length would be another option as well.

Comment: I understand, I have considered all those options but I would like the TextView to stay on one line and look complete and static. I thought it would be simpler but I see that it is not so common, I hope to find a solution, otherwise I will have to consider one of your options. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now, I changed my LinearLayout to a ConstraintLayout and put a view of the same color as my textview, just behind:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout...>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/week"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/week"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"/>

            <TextView...>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set a fixed width for your outer `LinearLayout`, then your requirement can be achieved by wrapping the `TextView` in another layout.

Please find sample code below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_border_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_text_highlight">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="2000"
            android:textColor="#cc000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_border_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_text_highlight">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text. Large text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="2000"
            android:textColor="#cc000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_border_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_text_highlight">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text. Very Large text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="2000"
            android:textColor="#cc000000" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code will generate the following output

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it, but I would like the size not to be fixed